# How to import neighboring python files in Python on Linux Server

Tags: python, linux, server, python-import

I've been working on a program that makes use of a linux server via Linode. The `__init__.py` file worked well until I started importing neighboring python files (the python files are placed in the same folder as `__init__.py`).

The program works fine locally, but when uploaded and executed from my linode server, it returns a 500 Internal Server error.

The following statement causes a runtime error

```
import interpreter
```

I am certain that importing a neighboring python file is the cause of the issue, as without the statement, everything works fine. I also only imported a dummy file called testScript.py (which only contained a module that printed "Hello World") and it also failed to run on the server.

I've attatched an image that shows the folder `__init__.py` and interpreter.py is in.

The folder containing `__init__.py` looks like this:

[image: 1]

Does anyone know why this happens? And how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi. Can you update your question with some more information around the runtime error you are getting? The traceback can probably give some more information on this.

Comment: I am unsure how to see the runtime errors, as I don't have a console to view them on.
Basically, I just go to the website's IP address, and it returns a webpage. I am unsure how to get access to the console to view the error

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. ****init**.py** was running (so to speak) in the base directory "/" rather than "/var/www/webApp/webApp".

```
subprogram_path = "/var/www/webApp/webApp/subPrograms"
sys.path.insert(0, subprogram_path)
import interpreter
```

The code above added the directory which contained interpreter.py to sys.path, which, as far as I understand, is basically a list that contains all the directories that are searched through when an import statement is read.

Now my program is able to make use of the modules within interpreter.py
[success message upon calling my webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAW4Z.png)

I'm happy :)